# How to make specific macro run faster

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Maybe anyone can help me with this part of macro?

```
Dim LastRow, DataCount, temp  As Double
        i = 1
        LastRow = 1
' skaicius sumeta i viena eilute
        Do While LastRow <> 0
            Range("A" & i).Select
            If ActiveCell.Value = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" Then
                'Cut all three row and paste
                DataCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(i & ":" & i))
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.row + 1, "I" & ActiveCell.row + 1).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount)
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.row + 2, "I" & ActiveCell.row + 2).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount * 2)
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.row + 3, "I" & ActiveCell.row + 3).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount * 3)

            Else
                LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 10))
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

If i understand correct the loop going row by row, but i have more then 5000 rows, so it is take a long time to be finish..

macro finding one cell with text "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" and cutting tree rows after it and combining into one row. I can show how it looks before and after.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: one quick tip is remove `Range("A" & i).Select` and just write `If Range("A"  & i) = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" Then` Also the cut operations and worksheet function call each time will slow things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do it is to do it in memory and write back the results. This could be sped up by reading everything into memory in one go / writing everything back in one go. But for now this does it line by line (Still should be faster). This will overwrite your source data so be sure to test this on a copy first.

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    Dim Results As Variant, tmp As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value2) = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" Then
                With Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 1).Offset(3, 8))
                    tmp = .Value2
                    .ClearContents
                End With
                ReDim Results(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1) * UBound(tmp, 2))
                For r = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
                    j = LBound(tmp, 2)
                    Do
                        Results(j + IIf(r > 1, UBound(tmp, 2) * (r - 1), 0)) = tmp(r, j)
                        j = j + 1
                    Loop While j <= UBound(tmp, 2)
                Next r

                Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, UBound(Results))) = Results
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See my comments under your original question above and try this tested code. If there is anything I did in the code that you do not understand, please comment and I will clarify.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateData()

    With Sheet1 'code name for worksheet 1, change as needed

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rowCounter As Long
        For rowCounter = lastRow To 1 Step -1

            If .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" Then

                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 1 To 3

                    Dim CopyRange As Range
                    Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(rowCounter + i, 1), .Cells(rowCounter + i, 1).End(xlToRight))

                    Dim cols As Integer
                    cols = CopyRange.Columns.Count

                    .Cells(rowCounter, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Resize(1, cols).Value = CopyRange.Value

                Next

                Dim rngRemove As Range
                If rngRemove Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngRemove = .Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Resize(3, 1)
                Else
                    Set rngRemove = Union(rngRemove, .Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Resize(3, 1))
                End If

            End If

        Next

        rngRemove.EntireRow.Delete

    End With

End Sub
```